# Android - table layout alternative (performance issue)

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to ask you, if there exists any "object", "layout", or whatever, what allows me to load quite a large amount of data.

Well. My solution works, but "works" is a quite relative statement.

I am loading data prom mysql in `AsyncTask`. Everything is working just fine, I get the `ResultSet`, I do the `res.next()` in `while` cycle and I get an array of data. Well, now I have 2 options.

1) do the writing on screen in `onPostExecute()` method looping through whole array.
(it is 2d array [][], first index is the record/line, second is the value of each column of the table. Both, index of number of columns, and the array are declared as global variables)
This means

```
for{
   for{
      }
   }
```

2) Use `onProgressUpdate()`, where I can pass only an index (int) and then inside onProgressUpdate get the exact value of that array.
This means
`publishProgress(i);` in `doInBackground() /*i is declared before while(res.next) and it has i++ inside it = it is number of each/actuall row*/`

and then only one for cycle inside onProgressUpdate()

```
TableRow tblr = new TableRow()
for(int j = 0 j<columncount; /*we know from previous thing, how many columns we have*/ j++){
   TextView tv = new TextView();
   tv.setText(dataArray[i /*this is the row form while czcle above*/][j]
   tblr.addView(tv)
}
teableLayout.addView(tblr);
```

The second solution is little less system-performance-consuming at first look, but, both ways are terrible.

Android has to locate tableView, then add row and then iside the row, add TextViews.
And this is veeeeeery slow, if you try to load table with more then, shall we say 300 rows with 15 columns, which about 1/3 of them are larger then some "small" INT value, like some tests/blobs.
The `doInBackground()` is relatively fast, you download the data fast if you have a good connection. But then, the looping for(s) to write it down freezes the UI for a unacceptable ammount of time.

And the `onProgressUpdate()` is not a solution as well, because the phone probably creates a new instance of task trying to write something in the display, but they can't access screen all together, so one has to write, then next, then next, and then, you have a queue of 1000+ awaiting tasks to perform its writing - and it freezes completely the UI until all is done.

So. 
Does exist some other table, which acts like real table of data, instead of creating table form textviews in rows, which takes literally whole computing capacity of device? (tested on xiaomi hongmi, 4-core@1.5Ghz)

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` or `RecyclerView` provides better performance for large amount of data to be displayed as a table view.And you don't need to load your data as a 2d array but just 1d to bind the data with view,thus use one less nested loop.

Also you can consider using something more efficient than `AsyncTask`,because default `AsyncTask` use only one `Thread` to do background work and don't perform well when doing some heavy work.You can consider using more `Threads`(or `Executor`) with `Handler` or config the `AsyncTask` with more `Threads` with `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`,if the background work is heavy.